# Html::dropDownList depending Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii2

I have a problem to connect two select. I would like the choice of a select filters the search of the second select statement.Both select take data from their tableDB but are not influenced each other. Can someone help me?

my first select customers take data from db table customers:

```
<?=
    Html::dropDownList('userlist', [],  
    ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find()->where('id',['company_id' => 
    'name'])->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name'), 
    ['prompt' => 'Select a User ...', 
    'class' => 'form-control', 
    'style' => 'width: 100%;']);
    ?>
```

my second select offers take data from db table offers:

```
<?=
   Html::dropDownList('offerslist', [],  
   ArrayHelper::map(Offers::find()->where('customer_id',['company_id' 
   => 'offers_n'])->orderBy('customer_id')->all(), 
   'id','offers_n','customer_id'), 
   ['prompt' => 'Select a Offert ...',
   'onchange' => 'change_user_list(this.value)', 
   'class' => 'form-control', 
   'style' => 'width: 100%;']);
   ?>
```

This is my function js:

```
 function change_user_list(company_id)
   {
   $.ajax({
   url: "<?= \yii\helpers\Url::to(['offers/userlist'])?>",
   type: 'get',
   data: {
   company_id: company_id
   },
   success: function (data) {
   document.getElementsByName('userlist')[0].innerHTML = data;
   }
   });
   }
```

this is my actionFucntion in the controller:

```
public function actionUserlist($company_id)
   {
   if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax)  {      
   $userlist = ArrayHelper::map(Customers::find()- 
   >where(['company_id' => $company_id])->orderBy('name')->all(), 
   'id', 'name');
   $string = "<option value>Select a Users</option>";
   foreach($userlist as $id => $name) {
   $string .=   "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>";
   }
    return $string;
   }
   }
```

Comment: it is hard to understand how you want your dropdowns to be working do you want that the user selected in the first list should update the offers in the second list and those offers would be against the user id selected in the first drop-down?

Comment: May you wanna use http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Comment: yep thx for help . the value for the two select are different.